# How to make directShow to Create graph automatically with available filters

Tags: windows, com, directx, directshow, source-filter

I want to use the Medialooks multisource filter in my application, This has entry in
        HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\
But still i have to Add this filter manually using **CLS_ID** and  **AddFilter** Function.

Is there any way so that **Renderfile** function of Dshow will automatically creates a graph by enumerating the filters from registry

Checked in **Grphedt** tool but if i manually insert and connect Filters I can play the videos properly.Otherwise it wont render automatically by building the graph

Answer (score 1):

Ability yo connect filters and obtain a topology of your interest is one thing, and having this sort of connection taking place during [Intelligent Connect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390342) is another thing. For Intelligent Connect and `RenderFile` the filters of interest must be apparently registered, and then they have accurate DirectShow registration details: merit, media types. Quite so often filters are lacking this registration (and at other times they are "over-registrating" themselves so that they are picked up when they are obvious misfit).

Even though you can re-register filter yourself (see [`IFilterMapper2::RegisterFilter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390036)) with alternate registration details, you typically do not do it. It's filter developer's business to register accurately. The better alternative for you is to build graph using `AddFilter` calls where you have fine control over graph construction. Or you might want to do it as a fallback construction method if `RenderFile` fails in first place.

Comment: How can i confirm filter is registered properly or not ?

Comment: You can review the registration with GraphEdit, GraphStudioNext or similar. Then compare to [Guidelines for Registering Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388793) and decide whether it is proper or not. Whether it matches the intention and what is supposed to be done by developer, or rather looks like a bug or inaccuracy.

Comment: I found like merit or filter is set to MERIT_DO_NOT_USE(0x002000) from grphedit tool .This is a source filter .Can i change the merit of filter myself ?

Comment: `IFilterMapper2::RegisterFilter` already mentioned above, or interactively using [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next).