# How to connect object to the filter graph?

Tags: c++, audio, directshow

What I need to do is - get decoded sample frames (like `vector<frames>`) from `DirectShow` in order to do it I follow this implementation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/using-the-sample-grabber

There is my implementation

```
bool coAudioPlayerSampleGrabber::LoadImp(SoundDataType dataType,
    unsigned char const * pData,
    int64_t dataLen)
{
    Cleanup();
    m_bReady = false;
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    assert(pData);
    assert(dataLen);
    m_memBuffer.resize(dataLen);
    memcpy(m_memBuffer.data(), pData, dataLen);
    m_memBufferDataType = dataType;

    m_pMediaType = new CMediaType();
    m_pMediaType->majortype = MEDIATYPE_Stream;

    switch (dataType)
    {
    case SoundDataType::WAV: m_pMediaType->subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_WAVE; break;
    case SoundDataType::MP3: m_pMediaType->subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG1Audio; break;
    default:            return false;
    }

    m_pMemStream = new CMemStream((BYTE*)m_memBuffer.data(), m_memBuffer.size());
    m_pMemReader = new CMemReader(m_pMemStream, m_pMediaType, &hr);
    if (FAILED(hr) || m_pMemReader == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not create filter - HRESULT 0x%8.8X\n", hr);
        return false;
    }
    //  Make sure we don't accidentally go away!
    m_pMemReader->AddRef();

    // *** Create the Filter Graph Manager

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pGraph));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        if (hr == CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED)
        {
            printf("coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED   CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph,...) FAILED hRes: %x  (CoInitialize has not been called)\n", hr);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED   CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph FAILED hRes: %x\n", hr);
        }

        return false;
    }

    hr = m_pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pControl));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED QueryInterface IMediaControl" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    hr = m_pGraph->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pEvent));

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED QueryInterface IMediaEventEx" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }   

    // *** end Create the Filter Graph Manager

    // *** Add the Sample Grabber to the Filter Graph
    // Create the Sample Grabber filter.
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SampleGrabber, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pGrabberF));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED CoCreateInstance CLSID_SampleGrabber" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    hr = m_pGraph->AddFilter(m_pGrabberF, LPCWSTR("Sample Grabber"));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED AddFilter m_pGrabberF" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    hr = m_pGrabberF->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pGrabber));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED QueryInterface ISampleGrabber" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // *** end Add the Sample Grabber to the Filter Graph

    // *** Set the Media Type
    hr = m_pGrabber->SetMediaType(m_pMediaType);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << "coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED SetMediaType" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }
    // *** end Set the Media Type

    IPin *ppinOut = m_pMemReader->GetPin(0);
    hr = m_pGraph->Render(ppinOut);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        printf("coAudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED to load (Render) audio file from data (hRes: %x)\n", hr);
        return false;
    }

    m_bReady = true;

    return m_bReady;
}
```

I get an error here :

```
IPin *ppinOut = m_pMemReader->GetPin(0);
    hr = m_pGraph->Render(ppinOut);
    if (FAILED(hr))                    <------------- HERE!!
    {
        printf("TV_AudioPlayerSampleGrabberImplementation::Load: FAILED to load (Render) audio file from data (hRes: %x)\n", hr);
        return false;
    }
```

Error code is - `0x8004025F`, which according to this error table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/error-and-success-codes means that

> Cannot perform the requested function on an object that is not in the filter graph.

I see there is an example in doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/using-the-sample-grabber#build-the-filter-graph

But this an example use path to file as a first param in this method `pGraph->AddSourceFilter(pszVideoFile, L&quot;Source&quot;, &pSourceF)`, I don't have path to file instead I have `m_pMemReader = new CMemReader(m_pMemStream, m_pMediaType, &hr)`.

Question is - How to connect object to the filter graph if I have `CMemReader` ?

**EDIT**

changed these lines

```
    m_pMediaType = new CMediaType();
    m_pMediaType->majortype = MEDIATYPE_Audio;            <---------- First line

    switch (dataType)
    {
        //case SoundDataType::WAV: m_pMediaType->subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_WAVE; break;
    case SoundDataType::WAV: m_pMediaType->subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_PCM; break;  <-------- Second line
    case SoundDataType::MP3: m_pMediaType->subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG1Audio; break;
    default:            return false;
    }
```

**EDIT2**

In order to include `m_pMemReader` to graph I added this line

```
hr = m_pGraph->AddFilter(m_pMemReader, NULL);
```

Then in I set media type as `MEDIATYPE_Audio` I get an error `0x80040200` - `The specified media type is invalid.` , if I try to use media type as `MEDIATYPE_Stream` I get follow error `0x80040266` -

> Pins cannot connect because they don't support the same transport.
> For example, the upstream filter might require the IAsyncReader interface, while the downstream filter requires IMemInputPin.

What is a problem here? What I undrstand from here is - my upstream filter is `CMemReader * m_pMemReader;` , but `CMemReader` under the hood it inherit from `IBaseFilter`, then my downstream is `IBaseFilter * m_pGrabberF;` which is also `IBaseFilter`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectShow is outdated. You should use MediaFoundation instead. I didn't test it but I think the following code will decode audio and let you manipulate raw audio frames (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/tutorial--decoding-audio):

```
IMFSourceReader *pReader = NULL;
hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL(L"C:\\users\\video", NULL, &pReader);
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Error opening input file");
}

IMFMediaType *type = NULL;
IMFMediaType *pPartialType = NULL;
hr = MFCreateMediaType(&pPartialType);
hr = pPartialType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
hr = pPartialType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);
// Set this type on the source reader. The source reader will
// load the necessary decoder.
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    hr = pReader->SetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, NULL, pPartialType);
}
hr = pReader->GetCurrentMediaType((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, &type);
//Do something with type which is a pointer to IMFMediaType
 
IMFSample *pSample = NULL;
IMFMediaBuffer *pBuffer = NULL;
BYTE *pAudioData = NULL;
DWORD cbBuffer = 0;
while(true){
    DWORD dwFlags = 0;
    hr = pReader->ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM, 0, NULL,  &dwFlags, NULL, &pSample);
    hr = pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&pBuffer);
    hr = pBuffer->Lock(&pAudioData, NULL, &cbBuffer);
    //Do something with the pAudioData which is an array of unsigned chars of lenth cbBuffer
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with the code and overall the code snippet is inconsistent, not even telling that one can't build it. You should probably create a small project and upload to GitHub to use as a reference.

Problems to resolve are:

1. there is no visible reason why `m_pMemReader` would have a suitable pin that belongs to filter graph
2. Sample Grabber is initialized with media type `MEDIATYPE_Stream` which contradicts to your intent to have decoded audio (you would need `MEDIATYPE_Audio`, `MEDIASUBTYPE_PCM` instead)
3. it is generally not a good idea to use `Render` method at all; I will leave [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37113973/868014) to read up on what problems are associated with use of DirectShow Intelligent Connect

Since you seem to be mostly trying to make it work blindfold, it would probably be a good idea to use [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) (analog of SDK [GraphEdit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directshow/simulating-graph-building-with-graphedit) tool) and build pipelines interactively to get an idea what kind of filter graph you would need to build. You will get a better idea about building similar gaph from code then.

Comment: I edited my question, my edit related to case 2 about types. But I didn't really got your idea about case 1 and 3. About first case as I see it - I created `CMemReader` gave it a stream of source bytes than I get `IPin` and pass it to `Render`, so I assume it should start render given source stream, no? And about case 3 - but what I need to use instead? Maybe you can add a code to your answer?

Comment: First, there is nowhere to add code to - you don't have buildable project. Second, the error you get is `VFW_E_NOT_IN_GRAPH` which is exactly what I wrote above in 1. You can't `Render` something that does not even belong to filter graph.

Comment: I edited my question `EDIT2`, could you please take a look

Comment: To be honest I don't see how it is related to this and earlier questions. Why would you even use CMemReader here.

Comment: "how it is related to" you mean error, right? I don't know, but it is what I get. As you can see in question I am using `CMemReader` in order to read byte stream. I don't have a file as a source, what I have is a byte pointer and size, so for this purpose I use  `CMemReader`. No?

Comment: Not really, you can't use `CMemReader` as simple as the way you outlined.

Comment: Hmm, I have such an example https://gist.github.com/alekseytimoshchenko/4c2d1ba77fd6e64aac0c4fd33d75ab3c where this approach works well. Maybe I am missing smth. I would like to ask you what do you think about @user123 answer? I tried to implement it looks like it works(for now from file, so I need to find a way to read from stream)

Comment: The problem with `CMemReader` is that it is not a part of this question and not even something currently documented. The way you brought it in does not add clarity to the question. @user123 mentioned newer media API Windows Media Foundation. It generally works, users might have considertions to use or not use it - but you always asked for DirectShow.

Comment: On DirectShow vs. Media Foundation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38707725/868014

Comment: Ok, I see, thanks. I just can't work out with `DirectShow`, but I checked `Media Foundation` example and looks like it works, but I still have a problem with read from stream as a source. Maybe you can help me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/64971831/5709159 I appreciate